# Trigger a jenkin job remotely with file parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I've a Jenkin Job which I want to trigger remotely, which should take file as a input.

Directory of file: C:\Users\PrashantGuptaC\Documents

File Name: file.txt

The postman post request seems success, but there are no parameters  shown in jenkin job. I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

I'm completely new  with Jenkins, so any suggestion would be Welcome.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

via curl below is the example. like this, you can use any tool like this approach

**Syntex**

```
curl JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters \
  --user USER:PASSWORD \
  --form FILE_LOCATION_AS_SET_IN_JENKINS=@PATH_TO_FILE
```

**Example**
I have a file parameter in Jenkins

[image]

```
http://localhost:8080/job/test/buildWithParameters \
  --user $JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_TOKEN \
  --form file=@/home/XYZ/m/myfile.yml
```

Note - `@` is needed, after that the file absolute path.

and from the postman, it will be like. Make sure you use Basic Auth and use Jenkins user and token in it.

[image]

Comment: Things you've mentioned worked partially. But while setting the path in Jenkins Suppose 'Documents/data/file.txt' (relative path) and passing a request from postman where file name is same 'file.txt', then I'm not getting any file in parameter.

When I don't specify any path, it do works

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a screenshot that explains to you - How to call the parameterized Jenkins job from the postman. Or Just explain what is not working and what have you done so far so that I will add more details. If this solves your question, Please accept the answer

Comment: When I provide File Location -> file. it works perfectly, but when giving some directory(Suppose C:\User\Document) it don't accept the parameter. 

Also can I give my data in this form
'data:text/plain;base64,U29tZSBEYXRh' , when I don't want give absolute directory path to file.  In this case file is taken from user input & then processed using filleReader in React.

Comment: along with the absolute path you have to specify `@` parameter if you are using curl. 

if you are suing any language like Java, Groovy, Python or Go, Make sure you read the file, prepare an IO stream, pass the necessary header to the Jenkins api.

I don't think convert file content to base64 will understand by Jenkins api.

Comment: In windows the path have to be given with double slashes : C:\\User\\Document